# How to parse JSON in shell script?

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

I run the curl command `$(curl -i -o - --silent -X GET --cert "${CERT}" --key "${KEY}" "$some_url")` and save the response in the variable response. ${response} is as shown below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 34
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-XSS-Protection: 1; 

{"status":"running","details":"0"}
```

I want to parse the JSON `{"status":"running","details":"0"}` and assign 'running' and 'details' to two different variables where I can print status and details both. Also if the status is equal to error, the script should exit. I am doing the following to achieve the task -

```
status1=$(echo "${response}" | awk '/^{.*}$/' | jq -r '.status')
details1=$(echo "${response}" | awk '/^{.*}$/' | jq -r '.details')
echo "Status: ${status1}"
echo "Details: ${details1}"
if [[ $status1 == 'error' ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Instead of parsing the JSON twice, I want to do it only once. Hence I want to combine the following lines but still assign the status and details to two separate variables -

```
status1=$(echo "${response}" | awk '/^{.*}$/' | jq -r '.status')
details1=$(echo "${response}" | awk '/^{.*}$/' | jq -r '.details')
```

Comment: What does your `curl` command look like? If you're throwing away the headers anywaym, you can keep them out of `$response` in the first place.

Comment: Added the curl command above

Comment: If you drop `-i`, you won't get the headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, **stop using the `-i` argument to `curl`**. That takes away the need for `awk` (or any other pruning of the header after-the-fact).

Second:

```
{
  IFS= read -r -d '' status1
  IFS= read -r -d '' details1
} < <(jq -r '.status + "\u0000" + .details + "\u0000"' <<<"$response")
```

The advantage of using a NUL as a delimiter is that it's the sole character that can't be present in the value of a C-style string (which is how shell variables' values are stored).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a construction like:

```
read status1 details1 < <(jq -r '.status + " " + .details' <<< "${response}")
```

You use read to assign the different inputs to two variables (or an array, if you want), and use `jq` to print the data you need separated by whitespace.

Comment: If you want to allow for arbitrary strings instead of relying on whitespace, you could use a nul byte as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321015/storing-jq-null-delimited-output-in-bash-array

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin already suggested, only retrieving the json is a better way to go. Poshi's solution is solid.

However, if you're looking for the most compact to do this, no need to save the response as a variable if the only thing your're going to do with it is extract other variables from it on a one time basis. Just pipe curl directly into:

```
curl "whatever" | jq -r '[.status, .details] |@tsv'
```

or

```
curl "whatever" | jq -r '[.status, .details] |join("\t")'
```

and you'll get your values fielded for you.