# Iterate over an array of objects and format the string

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "classname": "Test endpoint",
    "name": "expect failure",
    "failure_system_out": "expected 404 Not Found\nError in test endpoint\n\tat Test._assertStatus"
  },
  {
    "classname": "Test inner functions",
    "name": "expect failure",
    "failure_system_out": "Example fo test\n\tExpect 4 and got 5"
  }
]
```

As you see the value in "failure_system_out" is a string containing newline chars (\n) and tab chars (\t).

I am trying to read the file, loop around the objects and print them with this code:

```
jq -c '.[]' myfile.json | while read i; do
    test_name=$(echo "$i" | jq -r .name)
    system_error=$(echo "$i" | jq -r .failure_system_out)
    printf "${system_error}"

done
```

The problem is that using this approach, printf doesn't print the script according the the new line & tab chars, but It prints something like this `expected 404 Not FoundnError in test endpointntat Test._assertStatus`
Basically, I think that jq -c removes the `\` char and therefore the printf doesn't work properly.

How can I iterate over an array of object stored in a file and keep the chars using to format the string?

Desired output for the first item:

```
expected 404 Not Found
Error in test endpoint
   at Test._assertStatus
```

Desired output for the second item:

```
Example fo test
    Expect 4 and got 5
```

Comment: Please add desired output!

Comment: Before `jq` manage to see the expanded variable the builtin `read` command removes the `\\``

Comment: Because the `-r` flag is not used. e.g. `read -r`

Comment: @Jetchisel can you please write the code which should work for this example?

Comment: `Desired output:`  What happened to `Example fo test...`?

Comment: Can someone explain me why my question got "-1" vote? It was just a question!!!!

Comment: @dventi3 I upvoted the question because I think it's a good question :D, justice has been served.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `jq` it's a scripting language on it's own.

```
$ jq -r '.[0].failure_system_out' /tmp/1
expected 404 Not Found
Error in test endpoint
    at Test._assertStatus
$ jq -r '.[1].failure_system_out' /tmp/1
Example fo test
    Expect 4 and got 5
$ jq -r '.[] | .name as $test_name | .failure_system_out as $system_error | $system_error' /tmp/1
expected 404 Not Found
Error in test endpoint
    at Test._assertStatus
Example fo test
    Expect 4 and got 5
```

As for using bash, first read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . I like using `base64` to properly transfer context from `jq` to `bash` and handle all corner cases.

```
jq -r '.[] | @base64' /tmp/1 |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=$(<<<"$line" base64 -d);
    test_name=$(<<<"$line" jq -r .name);
    system_error=$(<<<"$line" jq -r .failure_system_out);
    printf "%s\n" "$system_error";
done
```

but it's not needed here, just a proper `while read` loop should be enough:

```
jq -c '.[]' /tmp/1 |
while IFS= read -r line; do
    test_name=$(<<<"$line" jq -r .name);
    system_error=$(<<<"$line" jq -r .failure_system_out);
    printf "%s\n" "$system_error";
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to weave amongst several goals, but in any case:

- there is no need for jq to be called more than once, and
- there should be no need to use base64 conversions, except possibly if the values corresponding to the keys of interest contain NULs.

If the goal is simply to emit the values of `.failure_system_out` then:

```
 jq -r '.[].failure_system_out' test.json
```

would do it.

If the values of both `.name` and `.failure_system_out` must be made available separately as bash variables, then consider:

```
while IFS= read -d $'\0' system_error ; do
    IFS= read -d $'\0' test_name
    printf "%s\n" name="$test_name"
    printf "%s\n" fso="$system_error"
    echo ""
done < <(jq -rj '.[] | [.name, .failure_system_out, ""] | join("\u0000")' test.json)
```

`readarray` could also be used -- see e.g.
[Storing JQ NULL-delimited output in bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321015/storing-jq-null-delimited-output-in-bash-array)

Answer (score 0):

[@KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66855256/5625547) works great and gives quite some more control.

Thought I'd still share this [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) only solution:

```sh
printf "%s\n" "$(jq -r -c '.[] | .failure_system_out' test.json)"
```

This will produce:

```
expected 404 Not Found
Error in test endpoint
    at Test._assertStatus
Example fo test
    Expect 4 and got 5
```