# JSON String processing injects quotes

Tags: json, bash, jq, echo

I get json encoded secrets from a Vaulwarden-Instance by their UUID.
I want so loop over any uuid and set environment variables accordingly.

For every field there should be variable (see below)

```bash
uuid_USERNAME=username
uuid_PASSWORD=password
uuid_FIELD_fieldname=fieldvalue
...
```

echo does inject single quotes so that the script breaks in the for loop ehich sets these field-based environment variables.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to handle this situation?

Best regards!

Here is the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for item in 55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a
do
  entry='{"passwordHistory":[{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"versteckt_name-leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"TestPasswort"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:45:56.662Z","password":"versteckt_name leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:28:04.951Z","password":"versteckt_name: versteckt_wert"}],"revisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:14:48.810Z","creationDate":"2024-02-18T21:04:02.811Z","deletedDate":null,"object":"item","id":"55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a","organizationId":null,"folderId":null,"type":1,"reprompt":0,"name":"TestName","notes":"notizen notizen1 notizen2","favorite":false,"fields":[{"name":"benutzerdefiniert_name leerzeichen","value":"benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen","type":0,"linkedId":null},{"name":"versteckt_name leerzeichen","value":"versteckt_wert leerzeichen","type":1,"linkedId":null},{"name":"bool_name leerzeichen","value":"false","type":2,"linkedId":null}],"login":{"fido2Credentials":[],"uris":[],"username":"TestBenutzername leerzeichen","password":"TestPasswort leerzeichen","totp":null,"passwordRevisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z"},"collectionIds":[]}'
  echo $entry
  echo ${item}_USERNAME=$(echo ${entry} | jq -r ".login.username")  > GITHUB_ENV
  echo ${item}_PASSWORD=$(echo $entry | jq -r ".login.password")  >> GITHUB_ENV
  echo ${item}_NOTES=$(echo $entry | jq -r ".notes | select( . != null )") >> GITHUB_ENV
  for field in $(echo $entry | jq -cr .fields[])
  do
    echo $field
    field_name=$(echo $field | jq -r ".name" | sed -e "s/ /_/g")
    field_value=$(echo $field | jq -r ".value")
    echo ${item}_FIELD_${field_name}=${field_value} >> GITHUB_ENV
  done
done
```

Here is the JSON in pretty:

```
{
  "passwordHistory": [
    {
      "lastUsedDate": "2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z",
      "password": "versteckt_name-leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"
    },
    {
      "lastUsedDate": "2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z",
      "password": "TestPasswort"
    },
    {
      "lastUsedDate": "2024-02-23T16:45:56.662Z",
      "password": "versteckt_name leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"
    },
    {
      "lastUsedDate": "2024-02-23T16:28:04.951Z",
      "password": "versteckt_name: versteckt_wert"
    }
  ],
  "revisionDate": "2024-02-23T17:14:48.810Z",
  "creationDate": "2024-02-18T21:04:02.811Z",
  "deletedDate": null,
  "object": "item",
  "id": "55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a",
  "organizationId": null,
  "folderId": null,
  "type": 1,
  "reprompt": 0,
  "name": "TestName",
  "notes": "notizen notizen1 notizen2",
  "favorite": false,
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "benutzerdefiniert_name leerzeichen",
      "value": "benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen",
      "type": 0,
      "linkedId": null
    },
    {
      "name": "versteckt_name leerzeichen",
      "value": "versteckt_wert leerzeichen",
      "type": 1,
      "linkedId": null
    },
    {
      "name": "bool_name leerzeichen",
      "value": "false",
      "type": 2,
      "linkedId": null
    }
  ],
  "login": {
    "fido2Credentials": [],
    "uris": [],
    "username": "TestBenutzername leerzeichen",
    "password": "TestPasswort leerzeichen",
    "totp": null,
    "passwordRevisionDate": "2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z"
  },
  "collectionIds": []
}
```

Here is the output:

```bash
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_USERNAME=TestBenutzername leerzeichen
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_PASSWORD=TestPasswort leerzeichen
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_NOTES=notizen notizen1 notizen2
{"name":"benutzerdefiniert_name
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
leerzeichen","value":"benutzerdefiniert_wert
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
leerzeichen","type":0,"linkedId":null}
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
{"name":"versteckt_name
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
leerzeichen","value":"versteckt_wert
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
leerzeichen","type":1,"linkedId":null}
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
{"name":"bool_name
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
jq: parse error: Unfinished string at EOF at line 2, column 0
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
leerzeichen","value":"false","type":2,"linkedId":null}
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_=
```

I tried executing this script and tried different methods e.g. `echo <<< $entry` or piping the output into files and then cat-ing them which didn't do the trick.

The variables should be set like mentioned in the text above.

Comment: My bash is a bit rusty but I think one of your main problems is in the second for loops declaration:
    $(echo $entry | jq -cr .fields[])
It looks like the console is having problems parsing and printing the spaces in the fields variable you have presented.

Comment: Start with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: 1) You need to double-quote a *lot* of variable references (e.g. `echo "$entry"` instead of just `echo $entry`) -- without double-quotes, the shell may mangle the output in unfortunate ways. 2) `for field in $(something)` will split the output into *words*, not entries (another example of non-double-quoted expansions doing the wrong thing). Use a `while read` loop instead -- see ["Iterate over an array of objects and format the string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854922/iterate-over-an-array-of-objects-and-format-the-string) for similar examples.

Comment: Also see "Q: How can a stream of JSON texts produced by jq be converted into a bash array of corresponding values?" in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are asking about is that the output of `$(echo $entry | jq -cr .fields[])` is being split on spaces, tabs and line feeds when passed to `for` (assuming the `IFS` env var has its default value). You want it to be split on line feeds only.

An easy way to fix that is to switch to using `read`.

Other changes:

- Fixed a slew of injection bugs. (Still assumes that all variables names are valid.)
- `jq -cr '.fields[]'` is wrong since you do want JSON. (Thankfully, the incorrect `-r` was simply ignored.)
- Different `echo` do different things. Best to avoid it in scripts to avoid surprises.
- Replaced `sed -e "s/ /_/g"` with the use of `gsub( " "; "_" )` in the jq program.
- Replaced `select( . != null )` with the shorter `values`.

Not fixed:

- The value of `$item` contains dashes, an unsuitable character for variable names.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

# to_shell_lit() - Creates a shell literal
# Usage: shell_lit="$( to_shell_lit "..." )"
to_shell_lit() {
   printf \'
   printf %s "$1" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"
   printf \'
}

output_var() {
   printf '%s=%s\n' "$1" "$( to_shell_lit "$2" )"
}

exec >GITHUB_ENV

for item in 55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a; do
   entry='{"passwordHistory":[{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"versteckt_name-leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"TestPasswort"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:45:56.662Z","password":"versteckt_name leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:28:04.951Z","password":"versteckt_name: versteckt_wert"}],"revisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:14:48.810Z","creationDate":"2024-02-18T21:04:02.811Z","deletedDate":null,"object":"item","id":"55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a","organizationId":null,"folderId":null,"type":1,"reprompt":0,"name":"TestName","notes":"notizen notizen1 notizen2","favorite":false,"fields":[{"name":"benutzerdefiniert_name leerzeichen","value":"benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen","type":0,"linkedId":null},{"name":"versteckt_name leerzeichen","value":"versteckt_wert leerzeichen","type":1,"linkedId":null},{"name":"bool_name leerzeichen","value":"false","type":2,"linkedId":null}],"login":{"fido2Credentials":[],"uris":[],"username":"TestBenutzername leerzeichen","password":"TestPasswort leerzeichen","totp":null,"passwordRevisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z"},"collectionIds":[]}'

   output_var "${item}_USERNAME" "$( printf %s "$entry" | jq -r '.login.username' )"
   output_var "${item}_PASSWORD" "$( printf %s "$entry" | jq -r '.login.password' )"
   output_var "${item}_NOTES"    "$( printf %s "$entry" | jq -r '.notes | values' )"

   printf %s "$entry" | jq -c '.fields[]' | while read -r field; do
     field_name=$(  printf %s "$field" | jq -r '.name | gsub( " "; "_" )' )
     field_value=$( printf %s "$field" | jq -r '.value' )
     output_var "${item}_FIELD_${field_name}" "$field_value"
   done
done
```

Output:

```bash
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_USERNAME='TestBenutzername leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_PASSWORD='TestPasswort leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_NOTES='notizen notizen1 notizen2'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_benutzerdefiniert_name_leerzeichen='benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_versteckt_name_leerzeichen='versteckt_wert leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_bool_name_leerzeichen='false'
```

---

Better yet, just do everything in jq.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

exec >GITHUB_ENV

for item in 55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a; do
   entry='{"passwordHistory":[{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"versteckt_name-leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z","password":"TestPasswort"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:45:56.662Z","password":"versteckt_name leerzeichen: versteckt_wert leerzeichen"},{"lastUsedDate":"2024-02-23T16:28:04.951Z","password":"versteckt_name: versteckt_wert"}],"revisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:14:48.810Z","creationDate":"2024-02-18T21:04:02.811Z","deletedDate":null,"object":"item","id":"55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a","organizationId":null,"folderId":null,"type":1,"reprompt":0,"name":"TestName","notes":"notizen notizen1 notizen2","favorite":false,"fields":[{"name":"benutzerdefiniert_name leerzeichen","value":"benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen","type":0,"linkedId":null},{"name":"versteckt_name leerzeichen","value":"versteckt_wert leerzeichen","type":1,"linkedId":null},{"name":"bool_name leerzeichen","value":"false","type":2,"linkedId":null}],"login":{"fido2Credentials":[],"uris":[],"username":"TestBenutzername leerzeichen","password":"TestPasswort leerzeichen","totp":null,"passwordRevisionDate":"2024-02-23T17:10:59.343Z"},"collectionIds":[]}'

   printf %s "$entry" | jq -r --arg item "$item" '
      "\( $item )_USERNAME=\( .login.username | @sh )",
      "\( $item )_PASSWORD=\( .login.password | @sh )",
      "\( $item )_NOTES=\(    .notes // ""    | @sh )",
      (
         .fields[] |
         ( .name | gsub( " "; "_" ) ) as $field_name  |
         ( .value                   ) as $field_value |
         "\( $item )_FIELD_\( $field_name )=\( $field_value | @sh )"
      )
   '
done
```

Output:

```bash
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_USERNAME='TestBenutzername leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_PASSWORD='TestPasswort leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_NOTES='notizen notizen1 notizen2'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_benutzerdefiniert_name_leerzeichen='benutzerdefiniert_wert leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_versteckt_name_leerzeichen='versteckt_wert leerzeichen'
55f8864a-ec88-410c-ab0e-8bee2119042a_FIELD_bool_name_leerzeichen='false'
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Literally took me hours to debug this...

I also saw the issue with jq -cr .fields[], in the real script this part worked for me so I did not pay as much attention to this part. 

Beautiful fix, thanks a lot !

Comment: Re "*Literally took me hours to debug this...*", You did it right, by inspecting the variables. Notice that `$item` was just `{"name":"benutzerdefiniert_name`?

Comment: Yes I did see the problem that there were quotes injected but I did not know how to prevent that. I didn't know that you have to doublequote the variables. Also the "exec >> output" statement was new for me. Learned a lot here!!

Comment: Quotes weren't injected. /// As used, it redirects stdout, saving us from using `>output` and `>>output` throughout. Obviously not necessary, but a little nicety